# Multi-node OpenStack with iSCSI storage

Tags: storage, iscsi, openstack, truenas, kolla-ansible

I’m trying to deploy a multi-node OpenStack environment using Kolla, Ansible, and Ubuntu server. I successfully added a partition to my Cinder storage using iSCSI. But I can't configure OpenStack to use this partition for VM provisioning. Why?

Comment: Without having more details about what exactly you tried (e.g. cli commands) and some error messages or logs this is just wild guessing. Please provide more details and add them to your question.